# Salesforce CLI is stuck in the authorization flow, and the device flow does not work

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, node.js

I'm trying to authorize an org locally, and with the `sfdx force:auth:web:login` command my web browser pops up and I successfully log in with my credentials. But then, when calling the node localhost app to recover the access token, the service does not work. The browser is stuck on "Waiting for localhost...".

It has been a while since this is happening with my machine. I was using the `sfdx force:auth:device:login` way of authorizing instead, but now when I try this one, I get another error:

> ERROR running auth:device:login:  Value is not a string

That's because I'm specifying the sandbox URL (`https://test.salesforce.com/`). When the `-r|--instanceurl` parameter is not present in the command, it works. But it is necessary if I want to authorize a sandbox.

---

The first one seems a local/permission issue on Linux machines (I have never seen anyone else with this problem on macOS or Windows). The second one seems like a bug on the CLI.

Is there anything I can do other than using another OS?

---

1. Running with `sudo` does not work.
2. Allowing port 1717 on UFW does not work.
3. Trying 1 and 2 at the same time does not work.
4. Using the version installed on the project's folder instead of the globally installed one does not work.

Comment: sfdx force:auth:device:login -r https ://test.salesforce.com - remove space

Comment: This issue appears to be discussed since December 14th, on [GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/767#issue-766586516).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a [bug](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/767) in the CLI. And it was [fixed on version 7.91+](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/767#issuecomment-801481515).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to login from windows, but every time I tried from Linux, for some reason it stops at waiting for localhost.

*sfdx force:auth:device:login -r https://login.salesforce.com*

This worked for me, to authorize my developer org.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same same issues running the cli in Linux.

For me what worked was the following workaround:

$ export SFDX_INSTANCE_URL=https://test.salesforce.com

$ sfdx force:auth:device:login

=== Action Required!
Enter 4VJV5RJQ user code in the verification URL https://test.salesforce.com/setup/connect

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue.
Installation actual version of auth plugin helped me
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/plugin-auth